# differentiating between to ...to VS. to ... ing

Tags: verbs

to take too much time making a decision

to take too much time to make a decision

Would you please tell me if they are grammatically correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both grammatically correct, but subtly different in meaning.  To take too much time MAKING a decision means that one actually spent a long time considering options. To take too much time TO MAKE a decision can include the same meaning above, but also includes the possibility that the person was stalling (or at least ignoring the question) for a long time, and THEN making a decision.